# Django - 500 internal server error after a collectstatic

Tags: django

trying a switch in production mode (debug=False in setting.py), I launched the python manage.py collectstatic command. from that moment when I try to connect to the site it gives me an internal error 500 even if I start the command via python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

this is my setting.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Game/template/game')
MEDIA_DIR =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'game/media')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '**************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<server-ip>','<server-domain>',]


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Accounts',
    'Game',
    'marketing',
    'Blog',
    'contactus',
    'django_filters',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'tempus_dominus',
    'bootstrap3_datetime',
    'django_summernote',
    'session_security',
]

SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'

#SESSION SECURITY SETTINGS
SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER = 540
SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER = 1800
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'session_security.middleware.SessionSecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'CicloPost.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'CicloPost.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]




# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it-IT'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

#MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'game/media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL =    '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL= '/'

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
```

i also have this error when i do collectstatic:

> Post-processing 'js/plugin/revolution/css/settings.css' failed!
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 316, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 353, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py",
>   line 188, in handle
>       collected = self.collect()   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py",
>   line 134, in collect
>       raise processed   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py",
>   line 293, in _post_process
>       content = pattern.sub(converter, content)   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py",
>   line 194, in converter
>       force=True, hashed_files=hashed_files,   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py",
>   line 131, in _url
>       hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py",
>   line 342, in _stored_name
>       cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))   File "/opt/ciclo_proj/CicloPost/ciclo_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py",
>   line 92, in hashed_name
>       raise ValueError("The file '%s' could not be found with %r." % (filename, self)) ValueError: The file
>   'js/plugin/revolution/css/openhand.cur' could not be found with
>   .

Comment: Are you receiving the same error when starting server with Debug=False?

Comment: no if Debug=False i don't have any error

Comment: What exactly results in exception? Collectstatic? Some URL access attempt? Can you share stacktrace?

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: Please clarify your question: when do you get this error, running what command? Do you get error in prod `in production mode (debug=False in setting.py), I launched` or dev `no if Debug=False i don't have any error` mode? It's not clear from your desription and some of your assertions conflict with each other.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong to write in the comment: if Debug=True no errors, if Debug=False i have 500 internal error

Comment: You're having 500 error while doing what? `I launched the python manage.py collectstatic command. from that moment when I try to connect to the site it gives me an internal error ` or `i also have this error when i do collectstatic:` ?

Comment: I did these steps: in setting i set debug=false , i try to go in the site and I did not have any error, but it did not load the image so i tried to do collectstatic and I have received this error " ValueError: The file 'js/plugin/revolution/css/openhand.cur' could not be found with ." . From this moment if i try to go in the site i have the 500 internal error

Comment: Do all of the files exist where you expect them to be? What does manifest file look like?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `DEBUG = False` you'll need to have a webserver that listens to port 80 on the url specified in `settings.STATIC_URL`, and serves the files from the directory specified in `settings.STATIC_ROOT`.

I would advise against having `settings.STATIC_ROOT` relative to `BASE_DIR` (it can get confusing, and normally you'll want static files from multiple projects served by the same static web server).